# Python IndexError in Power BI query, but not in PyCharm with the same code

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm, powerbi

I have a `Python` script that is working fine in `PyCharm`, but when I execute it in a `PowerQuery` I get this error:

```
HoldUdeEloFoer = current_elos[HoldUdeId]
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

This is the part of the code that is causing problems:

```
    current_elos = np.ones(shape=(n_teams)) * mean_elo

        for idx, game in games.iterrows():
            (HoldHjemmeId, HoldUdeId, score) = getWinner(game)

            HoldHjemmeEloFoer = current_elos[HoldHjemmeId] 
            HoldUdeEloFoer = current_elos[HoldUdeId]
```

When I print the types in PyCharm i get:

- HoldUdeEloFoer=numpy float 64
- HoldUdeId=Int
- current_elos=numpy.ndarray

I've tried putting the expression in `np.array(x, dtype=int)` and explicitly defining the variables as different data types, but I haven't found a solution yet. I've run a different script in the same `PowerQuery` with both `Pandas` and `Numpy`, so the `virtualenv` is working fine.

Comment: You already knew that it works in the IDE. To debug this, you should print the types *when run in PowerQuery* and post those.

Comment: I've tried to uncover the datatypes, but printing in the PowerQuery-editor, so I've used raise Exception to get the values from the variables: 
HoldUdeEloFoer 1500.0
Exception: [1500. 1500. 1500. 1500.]
HoldUdeId: 2. Could the regional language settings be confused by punctuation?